# Why is $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^k}}}=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

here's my attempt:$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n^k}}}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}}}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}{\frac{n-1}{n}}=\infty$$ What's wrong and how do i get $=1?$

Comment: There is a mistake: $\sum_{k=2}^\infty (\frac{1}{n})^k = \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{n}} $

Comment: Ah, you're right!! Thanks!!!

Comment: No problem, can you finish from here?

Comment: Sure, now it's  easy!

Comment: ;p would recommend answering your own question below. Let's others check your solution as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^k}= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1/n^2}{1-1/n}= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n-1)}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \left( 1-1/n \right)= 1.$$
Lastly we have done telescoping summation.